# Display GET data from PHP MySQL in Xcode 8 (Objective-c)

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, xcode8

I managed to get the data **"data1"** and **"data2"** from PHP MySQL database.

**Output :**

```
[{"d1":"data1","d2":"data2"}]
```

And my question is how to display it in view controller screen?

I named the label with **myLabel1** and **myLabel2**

**viewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myLabel1,myLabel2;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSError *error;
    NSString *url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://localhost/label.php"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url_string]];
    NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Output : %@", json);

}
```

Comment: See my answer @AlotJai

Comment: @AlotJai are data1 and data2 strings?

Comment: yup. both are string type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `JSON` response format, its clear that your `data` hierarchy will be `array` -> `dictionary` -> `key`,`values`.

So first you will have to get array as:

```
NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

which you have already done well.

The next step is to dive into `dictionary`.

So get your first `dictionary` as

```
NSDictionary *dict = [json firstObject];
```

This dictionary will have your `key` `value` pairs which you will need to access. So het them like this:

```
NSString *data1 = [dict valueForKey:@"d1"];
NSString *data2 = [dict valueForKey:@"d2"];
```

Now finally set these values to your text:

```
myLabel1.text = data1;
myLabel2.text = data2;
```

Comment: @AlotJai Welcome brother . Happy Coding..!!

Comment: Hi brother, can you help me on this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41539809/send-textfield-value-into-php-mysql-using-x-code-8-objective-c-with-or-without